# How can we stop backend process?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

In my spring boot application, I have below REST service

```
@GetMapping("/testThread")
public Map<String, Object> testThread(HttpServletRequest request){

    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this web service, I am calling from **POSTMAN** tool and in this webservice loop is running 100 000 times.

My requirement is after calling web service from postman then i am able to cancel that request by using **Cancel Request** button, then in back end 
 loop also should stop.

As of now loop is completing its execution.

Do we have any option to do so ?

Comment: You do have options to do so.  What have you tried?  (Also, simply stating you throw `InterruptedException` won't make it happen.  You need to add `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { throw new InterruptedException(); }` or similar into the loop for that.)

Comment: @user2478398   i have updated code in question, removed unused throws statement,
can you pls suggest some good link to fulfil  this requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two prototype options, the first is the requesting thread somehow cancels the request. As you are doing the work before you return the response you could in-theory send some data down the pipe with every iteration, for example, a space character and then flush the output writer. If the caller has closed the pipe you will get an IOException and that will terminate the loop. It's very hacky though.

The alternative is to return some sort of identifier for the worker thread so that a cancel command can be sent which identifies which thread is should be cancelled. To do this you are going to need to push your worker thread into a new thread and return a response that contains the worker identifier immediately. That means the initial client call gets a response straight away even though the worker thread is still working.

Note that the example below only works in a single server or sticky load-balanced environment. You could, of course, extend the state map to a database table for more complex architectures.

You may also want to add further endpoints to get the current state or results.

```
private enum State {
   Running,
   Cancel
}

private final Map<String, State> state = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

@GetMapping("/cancelThread/{id}")
public Map<String, Object> testThread(@PathVariable String id) {
    state.computeIfPresent(id, (k, v) -> State.Cancel);
}

@GetMapping("/testThread")
public Map<String, Object> testThread(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    state.put(id, State.Running);

    executor.submit(() -> doWork(id));

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("transactionId", id);
    return response;
}

private void doWork(String id) {
    executor.submit(() -); 

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
          if (state.get(id) == State.Cancel) {
              break;
          }

          System.out.println(i);
        }
    } finally {
        state.remove(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i need one suggestion, Instead of state map if i use database table so performance wise it will not be good like in every loop iteration i am making one Db query to read thread status  correct ?,  so i think i should use map instead of db so i can put state map in servlet context and whenever i need to access map i will get it from servlet context and after changing the state again will put map in servlet context.   will it be ok ?

Comment: The point of putting in some kind of centralised service is if you are in a load-balanced environment where a cancel request MAY not necessarily hitting the same service that the worker is running on. Alternatively, you could look at using a message queue. 

However, if you are only running a single server then you will be fine justing using a single Map in the same controller.

Comment: Before your answer i was searching for solution i found below ..
Please have a look .. In testThread method i am generating thread id Thread.currentThread().getId() that id i am returning
in resp and i created  another rest killThread here i am passing threadId and in this method i am killing that particular thread 
 Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
   for (Thread thread : setOfThread) {
    if (thread.getId()==threadId) {
     thread.stop();       
       }
   }
can you suggest will it be fine or not ?

Comment: The problem with relying on the thread id is that you don't know what you are killing. For example, what happens if I call killThread with a thread id but the thread with id is no longer processing the original workload but doing something completely different because either the thread itself or the id have been resused?

Comment: I have accepted that answer..  still have one question .. if suppose there is no any loop in my doWork implementation it will have thousand lines of code then how this solution will work  OR any other option ?