# Spring Boot How to Cancel API Request After Sometime

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have API exposed which sends a data to some other application, currently my code look like this :

```
     @PostMapping("/run/}")
        public ResponseEntity<Void>  runQuery(@PathVariable String timeToRun) {
              
                      for(int i = 0 ; i < timeToRun ; i++) {
                          // Do some logic
}
                    
        }
```

Let say i have 10 API request comes simultaneously, with different `timeToRun` parameters after sometime lets say 2 users want to stop their API request execution i.e `stop runQuery method` for those users, how i can maintain the state and how i can stop those 2 API request.

Comment: boring one... use a db to store cancel requests userid + jobid, then check in the loop if an entry is present

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606665/how-can-we-stop-backend-process

Answer (score 0):

I think, we need a bit more understanding here. When you say after some time, you want to stop the execution for two apis,

1. how will you identify which apis and when to stop, looks like you would need another param there.

Impl logic,

- Run each logic in a separate thread, and kill the thread, when you want